# Timing out issue in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code below is used to perform some simple functions in a Google Sheet.
It creates two new sheets (makes them (0) and (1), names them, and adds color) and hides another sheet.
The code has been extremely unreliable. If I create a blank google sheet and test it works fine but when I add it to the live version of the sheet it times out and fails to run all the code.
I also tested copying the live version (in case there was some corruption in the file) and initially it seemed to work but then the same problem occurred. I am brand new to app script so perhaps I am missing something obvious. I would appreciate any suggestions.

```
function New_Tabs() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "M/d") //sets format for current 
  date as month/day

  //Selects and activates the Day_date sheet / Gets calculated date info
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Day_Date');
  sheet.activate();
  var val = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,6).getValue();

  //Logger.log(val) Used this to check the value was pulled correctly

  //Insert the sheet for today's date - Data from portal/Excel macro will be pasted here
  spreadsheet.insertSheet(0); //Makes it the first sheet
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName(val); //pulls calculated date from Day_Date sheet
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setTabColor('#00ff00'); //Colors the sheet tab green

  //Insert the sheet for Logistics
  spreadsheet.insertSheet(1); //Makes it the second sheet
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName("Logistics " + curDate ); //names the sheet with text 
  and current date
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setTabColor('#00ff00'); //Colors the sheet tab green


  //trying to slow down to make hiding the tab more reliable
  Utilities.sleep(2000);// pause for 2 seconds


  //selects the sheet for today's date - Data from portal/Excel macro will be pasted here
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(val), true);

  //trying to slow down to make hiding the tab more reliable
  Utilities.sleep(2000);// pause for 200 milliseconds

  //selects the Day_date sheet and hides it
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Day_Date'), true);
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideSheet();


  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Completed");

};
```

Comment: What does the live version mean?

Comment: Cooper - "live" version is simply the google sheet that multiple users have been using for some time. My goal was to add code to automate part of the process to add new sheets in it each day. I will try the code and report back (I have to wait until after hours to test). Thanks so much for your quick response!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function New_Tabs() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "M/d");
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Day_Date');
  const val = sh.getRange(2,6).getValue();
  let ns = ss.insertSheet(0);
  ns.setName(val); 
  ns.setTabColor('#00ff00'); 
  let ns1 = ss.insertSheet(1);
  ns1.setName("Logistics " + curDate ); 
  ns1.setTabColor('#00ff00');
  ns.hideSheet();
  ss.toast("Completed")
}
```